# Realloc a table of structures that has table in it

Tags: c, structure, realloc

I am trying to write a programe that will store data in a table of structures. My problem is that i can't figure out why my realloc isn't working.

I am trying to realloc a table that is in a table of structures (sounds confusing, i know), but it won't work. Here is the part of my program i have a problem with:

```
typedef struct {
    int *node;
    int l;
}przejscie_t;

void czytaj(przejscie_t **graf, int vp, int vk){

    *graf=realloc(*graf,(vp+1)*sizeof(przejscie_t));
    (*graf)[vp].l=1;
    (*graf)[vp].node=realloc((*graf)[vp].node,(*graf)[vp].l*sizeof(int)); //it crashes here
    (*graf)[vp].node[(*graf)[vp].l]=vk;
    
}
```

Comment: To use realloc `(*graf)[vp].node` must be allocated first with either malloc/calloc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(*graf)[vp].node=realloc((*graf)[vp].node,(*graf)[vp].l*sizeof(int)); //it crashes here
```

`realloc` needs a valid initialized pointer as first parameter (or `NULL`, in this case it stands as if `malloc` was called), since `(*graf)[vp].node` is not initialized you are passing garbage.

Answer (score 1):

If your struct was initialized with `calloc()` OR set to zero with `memset()` (or manually) OR `(*graf)[vp].node` was set to `null`, `realloc()` would actually acted like `malloc()` for the required size.

> If ptr is a null pointer, `realloc()` behaves like `malloc()` for the specified size.

However, if you did not set your structure's memory or node pointer to zero when initializing the structure, you are probably passing garbage to your realloc, which gives access to unwanted memory and can cause many problems.

I can only strongly advise you to always initialize your tables/structures to zero before doing anything with them.

Fun fact:

> `realloc()` would act like `free()` if size is set to 0 and ptr is not null.
> Source : Relatively any `realloc()` manual you can find that respect the common standards.